# Not able to sort columns on Matrix in Power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a Matrix table in Power bi

```
Alarm_Type    0-50   100-150  50-100 
a              2        5       1
b              4        6       7
```

This is how I have data in my matrix table.
[image]
Here if you see I have 50-100 days column in my matrix I want that column should come after 0-50 days. Is that possible in Matrix

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an additional column to the table with an integer of the order you want. Then once it is present, select the column and in the ribbon, select `Sort by column` and here select the new column with the integer.

[image]

More info on [Sort one column by another column in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column?tabs=powerbi-desktop)